# Smart Energy Tracking / Metering Receptacle Outlet

Tags: receptacle, energy

I am searching for a power receptacle outlet that tracks and reports energy usage like a KillAWatt device but looks like a regular receptacle and connects to my WiFi so I can access it via phone app.

The closest item to what I was looking for is an Insteon Remote Control On/Off Outlet but it does not have the ability to track energy usage.

Does anybody know of a power receptacle outlet (in wall) that can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look into sonoff swtiches, some have power monitoring built-in

Comment: Thanks but these are similar to Elgato Eve Energy.  They stick out of the wall.

Comment: you're using it wrong if it's visible: https://www.itead.cc/sonoff-pow.html

Comment: Thank you for replying.  The problem with this one is that it is not a receptacle for me to plug in devices.   I guess it could work if I had a double gang box and used one side to hold this device while the other side is a receptacle   In my case, it is a one gang box and I am looking for someone that has it all integrated into one package.

Comment: the "receptacle outlet (in wall)" threw me off somehow. there's lot of modular options, the answer lists a few

Comment: I just did further searching and did find something this time but it appears to not work as expected according to a lot of reviewers.  Basically, I am looking for something like this but does energy monitoring on both outlets.  Here is a link to it on Amazon.  https://www.amazon.com/Quirky-POTLK-WH01-Outlink-Remote-Outlet/dp/B00P1Q2MPY

Answer (score 1):

[iDevices Switch](https://store.idevicesinc.com/idevices-switch/) is a point of use power meter. With the app you can toggle the power to the device and access the energy consumption. It doesn't require a IoT Hub, it will connect directly to your WiFi network, but it will also work with Apple HomeKit.

[Elgato Eve Energy](https://www.elgato.com/en/eve/eve-energy) is another point of use power meter. With the app you can toggle the power to the device and access the energy consumption. It needs a Apple HomeKit (other IoT Hubs may work too), because it only has Bluetooth LE for connectivity and can't connect directly to your WiFi network.

Unfortunately the first two options don't look like a regular electrical receptacle. I'm not sure if that product exists for a point of use power meter. You would need to install something at the main breaker box to keep everything inside the walls:

[Sense](https://sense.com) is an option for whole house energy consumption. It works by installing CT clamps around the power mains at the breaker box. It can identify large appliances like washing machines, electric dryers, dishwashers, and electric ovens based on the current "fingerprint" that it detects. This would be invisible to the end user, but doesn't fit your needs.

If you needed more detail than that, another option is the [TED Pro Spyder](http://www.theenergydetective.com/spyder). This works similarly to the Sense, but you add CT clamps to each individual circuit instead of just the mains. This will narrow down the usage to an individual circuit, but still not get you to the level of data you're looking for unless you run dedicated circuits for each device you want to monitor.

Comment: I've looked at Sense in the past and I read that it only identifies large loads and completely misses a lot of small loads.  In my application, I would like to isolate it down to the outlet level because I may not know nor do I care what people are plugging in.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this up.  I have been seen variations of the solutions that you mentioned and all of them either requires me to have a giant adapter which is removable or requires me to re-wire my house.  Hopefully, something that looks like a standard outlet will be available in the near future.